# Rails 6 - permit "dynamic" hash params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

This button redirect of course to form_for create new message:

```
<%= link_to "Send message" , new_message_path( :message => { :user_id => @profile.user.id, :category => 1 } ) %>
```

but I see this:

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in MessagesController#new

def new

    @message_new = current_user.messages_send.new(params[:message])

end
```

In my old script in Rails 4.0.0 it works ... I read some I try to make it like this in ***messages_controller***

```
def message_params
  params.require(:message).permit(:some_params ... ,  :message => {})
end
```

but still nothings change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few comments. I don't understand why your code is permitting a `message` hash inside the permitted attributes for `message` params, and it seems like it could be due to a misunderstanding about how permitted params work. Example:

```rb
class Message
  belongs_to :user

  validates :user, presence: true
  validates :category, presence: true

  # Let's say a Message has `user`, `category`, and `text` attributes
end

# Controller should look something more like this:
def new
  # Using message_params validates params' structure before using it to create an object
  @message = Message.new(message_params)
end

# Syntax: params.require(:object).permit(*permitted_attributes)
def message_params
  # This checks that params[:message].keys is a subset of [:user_id, :category, :text]
  params.require(:message).permit(:user_id, :category, :text)
end

# Permitted params should be structured like this example:
params: { 
  message: {
    user_id:  12,
    category: 1,
    text:     'Eat a plant!'
  }
}
# Note: `user_id`, `category`, and `text` are _permitted_ as params, 
# but their presence in the `message` hash is not required 
# (only the `message` key is required)

# Params like this will raise an error when using `message_params` 
# because `state` isn't defined as permitted in the `message_params` definition:
params: { 
  message: {
    user_id:  12,
    category: 1,
    text:     'Eat a plant!',
    state:    'initial'
  }
}
```

- Your initial code was simply calling `params[:message]` to pass the attributes of a message (e.g., `user_id`, `category`, and `text`) to the Message constructor without validating them.

  - This means that your initial code tries to create the object with *anything* you pass to it (e.g., when the params are  `{ message: { goblin: 'Spaghetti! } }` it tries to create the object as `Message.new(user_id: current_user.id, goblin: 'Spaghetti!')`).
- When you switch to using strong parameters, you switch to calling the `message_params` method instead

  - This method first fetches your params, which are an ActionController::Parameters object.
  - It then calls the [require](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.5/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-require) and [permit](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.5/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit) methods on the parameters object to validate that the parameters don't contain any additional keys that are misspelled or otherwise not defined as permitted
  - If the params don't follow the structure you define as permitted in `message_params`, it raises ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError because you're trying to pass it an attribute that isn't permitted.

Recommendations:

- Try playing around with permitted params in a Rails console:

  ```rb
  rails console

  def validate_params(params_hash)
    params = ActionController::Parameters.new(params_hash)
    params.require(:message).permit(:user_id, :category, :text)
  end 

  good_params = {
    message: {
      user_id: 14,
      category: 1
    }
  }
  validate_params(good_params)
  => <ActionController::Parameters {"user_id"=>14, "category"=>1} permitted: true>
  validate_params(good_params.deep_merge(message: { text: 'Spaghetti!' }))
  => <ActionController::Parameters {"user_id"=>14, "category"=>1, "text"=>"Spaghetti!"} permitted: true>

  bad_params = good_params.deep_merge(message: { goblin: 'Spaghetti!' })
  => {:message=>{:user_id=>14, :category=>1, :goblin=>"Spaghetti!"}}
  validate_params(bad_params)
  Unpermitted parameter: :goblin # observe raised error
  => <ActionController::Parameters {"user_id"=>14, "category"=>1} permitted: true>
  ```
- Try reviewing the RoR Guide on Strong Params: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters

Answer (score 0):

If someone will search for answer:

```
def new

    @message_new = current_user.messages_send.new(message_params) /// not params[:message]

end
```

and of course:

```
def message_params
  params.require(:message).permit(:some_params ... ,  :message => {})
end
```